# Printing each objects of class Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, for-loop, object

The class function below creates an object for `Account1` and `Account2`. How would I be able to print the different object values outside of the for loop?

```
accounts= {'Account1': OrderedDict([('AccountName', 'Account1'), ('APIkey', 'xczccdfc'), ('APIsecret', 'sdasdadsadcd')]), 'Account2': OrderedDict([('AccountName', 'Account2'), ('APIkey', 'asdasdadcrf'), ('APIsecret', 'asdase346')])}

class Dummy:
    pass

for account in accounts:
    '''
    Create a dummy function  to update APIkey and APIsecret, 
    here then reference it as infos.key or infos.secret in stats.auth()
    '''
    dummy = Dummy()
    dummy.key = accounts[account]["APIkey"]
    dummy.secret = accounts[account]["APIsecret"]
    
print(Account1.key)
print(Account2.key)
```

Comment: Does the `dummy.keys` and `dummy.secret` get overwritten?

Comment: No -- did you see my answer? It will set them under each instance of the class `Dummy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although overuse/abuse of the `global` keyword is generally frowned upon/considered un-Pythonic, you can add your `Dummy` classes to the "dictionary" of global variables.

I was able to get your expected behavior by initializing the class with your attributes this way:

```
class Dummy():
    def __init__(self, account_name):
        global accounts
        self.key = accounts[account_name]["APIkey"]
        self.secret = accounts[account_name]["APIsecret"]

for account in accounts.keys():
    globals()[account] = Dummy(account)

print(Account1.key)
print(Account2.key)
```